# Hangfire fetches but doesn't queue

Tags: hangfire

I am having issue where when I trigger a hangfire task it doesn't process.  It shows as fetched but not queued.

[image]

If I fully delete the hangfire schema and restart my application then I am able to run the task to completion but then subsequent triggered tasks go into the same fetched state.

If I look in succeeded then there is a count for a succeeded task but nothing shows:

[image]

The code itself executes fine (on first attempt after schema built).  It looks like some error is happening on task completion but I see no error in the logs.

I am using Hangfire.PostgreSQL provider.

How can I fix/debug this?

Comment: Hi Guerrilla, We have same problem. Have you found any proper solution?

Comment: I used an older version

Comment: Thanks. It worked.